# Acumatica Validation for sales order

Tags: validation, acumatica

I want to perform few validations on Sales order screen, I am comparing the Customer(customerID) field and the Customer Order(CustomerOrderNbr) field and try to give an error message if both the fields match.

I am not a programmer but I tried some code which is giving lot of errors and i'm not able to fix it...

```
 namespace PX.Objects.SO
{
  public class SOOrderEntry_Extension:PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
  {
        public const string ordernbrErrorMessage = "Customer name and customer number cannot be same.";


    public void SOOrder_RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
    {
      if (!ValidateCustomerID(sender, e.Row as SOOrder))
            {
                PXUIFieldAttribute.SetError<SOOrder.customerID>(sender, e.Row, ordernbrErrorMessage);
            }
     }



      public bool ValidateCustomerID(PXCache sender, SOOrder soOrder)
        {
            if (soOrder != null)
            {
                string soCustomerID = PXSelectorAttribute.GetField(sender, soOrder, typeof(SOOrder.customerID).Name, soOrder.CustomerID, typeof(Customer.acctCD).Name) as string; 
                string soCustomerOrderNbr = soOrder.CustomerOrderNbr; 

                if (soCustomerID != null && soCustomerOrderNbr != null)
                {
                    return !soCustomerID.Trim().Equals(soCustomerOrderNbr.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                }
            }             

            return true;

        }
  }
}
```

And this is my 1st entry with some customer name and order number

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gybBS.png)

And this is my 2nd entry with same customer name and order number

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7t5g.png)

After doing the changes in the code it isn't showing any error message...I restarted the website and checked but no results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the syntax errors below. However I would be inclined to think this validation has no practical use case. CustomerID is an integer (number) field in the database that identifies the customer record, usually this is not shown to the user. CustomerOrderNbr is a free form text field that can contain any string value entered from the user. I wouldn't expect the user to enter a CustomerID in CustomerOrderNbr.

**EDIT**: changed SOOrder.CustomerID by Customer.AcctCD

```
namespace PX.Objects.SO
{
    public class SOOrderEntry_Extension:PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
    {
        public const string ordernbrErrorMessage = "Customer name and customer number cannot be same.";

        public void SOOrder_RowPersisting(PXCache sender, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
        { 
            if (!ValidateCustomerID(sender, e.Row as SOOrder))
            {
                PXUIFieldAttribute.SetError<SOOrder.customerID>(sender, e.Row, ordernbrErrorMessage);
            }
        }

        public bool ValidateCustomerID(PXCache sender, SOOrder soOrder)
        {
            if (soOrder != null)
            {
                string soCustomerID = PXSelectorAttribute.GetField(sender, soOrder, typeof(SOOrder.customerID).Name, soOrder.CustomerID, typeof(Customer.acctCD).Name) as string;                   string soCustomerOrderNbr = soOrder.CustomerOrderNbr; 

                if (soCustomerID != null && soCustomerOrderNbr != null)
                {
                    return !soCustomerID.Trim().Equals(soCustomerOrderNbr.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                }
            }             

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason I want to implement this validation is because I don't want the same customer to have the same order number each time a new order is raised...

Comment: But it gives the error even if the Customer Order Number is empty or changed... I just want it to raise error when both the fields match

Comment: I changed ValidateCustomerID in my answer to invert the values. Return true instead of false.

Comment: For me it isn't working even after changing the return to true...still if I enter any other customer order number it gives error

Comment: It's a one character difference but has big impact.

Comment: yeah...i changed return as true

Comment: Return true will handle the case of blank field. The other Return needs to be prefixed with the not operator ! to invert the values. I updated my answer to have the not operator on the first return condition.

Comment: yes... i changed both the return statements 
return !soCustomerID.Equals(soCustomerOrderNbr);
                }
            }             

            return true;

Comment: Can you be more specific about the exact error you're having? I can't replicate it on my side. Only thing I can suggest is to reset website using IISRESET. Still thinks it makes no sense to compare ID and Nbr field though.

Comment: Look into the folder App_RuntimeCode in your website instance folder, check that the code you changed was properly published to the website.

Comment: When I change both the return statements it doesn't pops up with any error...but even if the customer name and order number are same it won't show the error

Comment: OK now I think we are on something. The check is on CustomerID which is why I raised some concern about the validation. CustomerID is a hidden  number that represent the customer record, it's not the Customer name. What you see displayed in that field is CustomerID description field which is Customer.acctName. Unlike CustomerID making validation on acctName makes sense and is likely what you're trying to achieve. You should change: string soCustomerID = PXSelectorAttribute.GetField(sender, soOrder, typeof(SOOrder.customerID).Name, soOrder.CustomerID, typeof(Customer.acctName).Name) as string;

Comment: acctName is the actual name of the customer, it's also possible you're looking to validate on the surrogate key of the customer, which is the ALL CAPS code for that customer, in this case you should substitute Customer.acctName by Customer.acctCD

Comment: Example Data for these fields:
customerID: 4891
acctName: USA Bartender School
acctCD: ABARTENDE

Comment: Another thing, unlike for Integer fields like CustomerID when comparing String fields like AcctName/AcctCD you usually want to ignore differences in casing and whitespace so you should change: return !soCustomerID.Trim().Equals(soCustomerOrderNbr.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

Comment: Thank you for explaining it so briefly!
I made the changes as u said in my code but still no error message pops up with same Customer name and Customer Order number...posted the images in my question

Comment: It's pretty hard to guess what the problem is when I can't replicate on my side. My recommandation for such case are to reset IIS, double check everything, use a debugger or PXTrace.WriteInformation to debug the validation.